# Reading feature class attributes with or without quotes in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, python-script-tool, where-clause, formatting

I'm working on a script that clips a batch of feature classes by a selection made in another feature class. The way it works is by reading the clip feature fields, then allowing the user to select the field they want to clip by. Then list of unique attributes `fro` the field is generated and the user can check multiple values to clip by. The multi value list is then passed to a SQL where clause that then gets incorporated into the `SelectLayerByAttribute` function.

The question that I've got doesn't really relate to the script (I've come up with some logic to get around the problem), but to how the attributes retrieved from the clip feature are formatted.

As I look at the values retrieved, some are formatted with single quotes around them (`'value'`) and others are not (`value`). And both conditions can exist in the same feature class and field.

Can anyone tell me why this is the case and if there is something I should be doing with my data to eliminate this condition?

I've included the script that I've been using.  Note the if statement that includes `.startswith` and `.endswith`.  That's the logic I've been using to get around the problem.

```py
import arcpy, os
workingGDB = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
clipLyr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
clipField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
clipValue = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workingGDB, datatype="FeatureClass")
valueList = clipValue.split(";")
whereList = []
for v in valueList:
    if v.startswith("'") and v.endswith("'"):
        whereValue = '{0}'.format(v)
        whereList.append(whereValue)
    if not v.startswith("'") and not v.endswith("'"):
        whereValue = "'{0}'".format(v)
        whereList.append(whereValue)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(clipLyr,"lyr")
whereClause = "{0} IN ({1})".format(clipField, ",".join(w for w in whereList))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)
records = arcpy.GetCount_management("lyr")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        filePath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)        
        outFile = filePath + "_clip"
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(filePath, "lyr", outFile)
        arcpy.Delete_management(filePath)
        arcpy.Rename_management(outFile, filePath)
```

Here is the validation code:

```
import arcpy
class ToolValidator(object):
  """Class for validating a tool's parameter values and controlling
  the behavior of the tool's dialog."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Setup arcpy and the list of tool parameters."""
    self.params = arcpy.GetParameterInfo()

  def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    return

  def updateParameters(self):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""

    if self.params[1].value and self.params[2].value:
        self.params[3].filter.list = sorted({row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(self.params[1].value, self.params[2].value.value) if row[0]})

  def updateMessages(self):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return
```

Comment: you have an extra letter on the 12 line (wherevValue) extra v, might not be the source of the problem. just to let you know

Comment: Just to confirm, are we discussing here quotation mark behaviour of TEXT fields only? As far as I know there is no other way of knowing that you are querying TEXT data with SQL but using single quotation. Other numeric types do not need that. Maybe this is related to the selected field, if it is numeric, there is no need for quotations. Of course if you are asking about TEXT field type only, I have no idea.

Comment: Generally speaking the single quotes should only be returned as part of a text field value if it actually contained a single quote as a literal character in the field.  Although it is frowned upon as a general practice, text fields allow users to type a single quote or a double quote and will store them as literal text characters, for example to represent feet or inches.  You would have to query for those characters and replace them in the actual field values to make everything consistent.  That should be the only way a single field returns a mixture of strings with and without quotes.

Comment: Actually, after looking at your code, the clipValue parameter is not being read directly from a field and has to be created by the user from a dialog or some text string they type as an input.  How are you building a checklist?  Is it part of a tool dialog?  Anyway, it most likely is due to some coding you have added to the user interface and not due to actual data being stored in the database (unless your users do include quotes as literal characters in fields as mentioned above).  Screenshot your interface.

Comment: The clip field and value are generated through validation of an ArcGIS script tool.  In short, the validation returns a list of fields in the feature class then returns a list of unique attribute values within the field.  As far as the attributes go, I've seen both conditions in the same field.  One value will have quotes and the next will not.  All fields are text and I see no reason that they would have been added as a literal character when the data was originally entered.  I'm out of the office for then next but can update with the validation code when I return.

Comment: Just to get the simple things out of the way: Do the quoted values have whitespace or other special characters? The arcpy API seems to do some funky things, including text formatting, when converting parameters to and from Python. Also, you don't really need to check for both the `'` characters and not, you could simplify your code a bit by using an else instead of the second if clause.

Comment: I've included the validation code so that you can see what the script tool is doing.  The quoted values do not have white space or special characters.  You're right about not needing the logic to test for both scenarios.  That part is actually a leftover from debugging where I was testing for a 3rd condition.  Can you point to any resources about how arcpy formats text?

Comment: I'm confused by your code snippet that uses a variable called `whereClause` which you do not set before that.  Can you ensure that your code snippet works up to where you are stuck, please?

Comment: The line was accidentally omitted when i added the code snippet.  I edited the code and added the line.

Comment: I have not been able to replicate this issue - are you able to provide some sample data where some values include the quote mark and others don't?  Maybe a screenshot from ArcMap of the data (only needs to be 3 or 4 records)